# Cannot get Rails 3.2 server running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to run [this app](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/), which had its last commit about an year ago.  After spending quite a while trying to get all the gem and gem dependecies to install (including commenting out the `metric-fu` gem), I am able to get the green light "bundle is complete" message.  However, when running server, I get the following error log:

```
Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environment.rb:5)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environment.rb:5)
Exiting
/Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environments/development.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/zallanx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:9:in `require'
    from script/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Are the old Rails 2.3 plugins throwing me off?  This is my first "real world" project after Hartl's Rails tutorial, so unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience dealing with this type of errors.  The Gemfile for the app, called smartr, is [linked](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/blob/master/Gemfile).  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://rubysource.com/get-your-app-ready-for-rails-4/) is an article which may help you to run old appllications wint Rails 4. Please read this part **No More vendor/plugins**, it describes how to solve one of your problems.

The second problem about sass-plugin can be solved by commenting 26 string in development.rb. It must be written somewhere else in Rails 3 app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the resource! While I am running Rails 3.2, I think this article will definitely help.  I also commented out `Sass::Plugin.options[:debug_info] = false` in `development.rb`, but it's still showing the error `/Users/zallanx/rails_projects/smartr/config/environments/development.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)`.. thanks again! I was hoping to update this myself to a rails 3.2 or 4 app.. but am a bit overwhelmed about where to start now :)

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error once when I had some 2.x plugins in the vendor folder. After I removed them, the error is gone.

Comment: This sounds promising - I don't really have a lot of experience dealing with items in the vendor folder.. how would I disable or uninstall them?  I see that there is an `uninstall.rb` file, but it is empty.  Thanks!

Comment: @daspianist Just `rm -r` them

Answer (score 1):

Sass is in the gemfile, but it's version is not limited. Since the project hasn't been modified in a year, the project is probably expecting an older version of Sass. You should try researching downgrading sass in the Gemfile and doing `bundle update` to see what happens. Also, Rails 3.2 was not out a year ago, so I wouldn't run this app on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like something called Sass::Plugin is either missing or not loading correctly from your app.

check if the above mentioned plugin is exist

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the advice.   Do you think undertaking a project which slowly upgrades an Rails app that was built around an year ago (by someone else) on 3.0.9 to Rails 3.2 (or even Rails 4) would be worthwhile task to take on? Thanks

Comment: it depends :), I think its not depending on technical aspect, but the commercial (how much worth the effort). But doing such a project will give you an immense experience new features of rails which I think is a good thing. But I'm sure it will be tough, but I personally think its worth it :)